# Estimating the binomial parameter $p$ for rare events

Tags: statistics, bayesian

Suppose we have an extremely large collection of red balls and green balls. If we let $R$ and $G$ be the events of drawing a red ball and drawing a green ball, respectively, and if we let $\Pr(R)=p$ then $\Pr(G)=1-p$. We also assume that the vast majority of the balls in our collection are green, implying $p \ll 1-p$.

We would like to estimate $p$ using the following experiment: sample from the collection 3 times by selecting 20 balls each time. Then starting with the uninformed prior distribution of $p$ as Beta$(1,1)$ we update the prior by Bayesian updating after each sample and compute the expected value of $p$ after completing the 3 samples.

So suppose we sample and get 20 green balls for each of the 3 samples. The final update of the prior distribution of $p$ is Beta$(1,61)$ and the expected value of $p$ is $E(p)=\frac{1}{62}\approx 0.01613$.

This seems to be a very high estimate and I think the problem is that I am starting the updating with an uninformed prior despite the fact that I know $p \ll 1-p$. Is there a way to justify a more informed prior in order to get a stronger conclusion? For example, if I believe that $p\le 0.01$ does it make sense to start with the informed prior Beta$(2,100)$?

Comment: Note that your updating scheme is equivalent to using a single sample of size 60.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might have better luck at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't see why not. On a related note - https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20520

Comment: @angryavian I noticed that too.

Comment: Seems your prior view is that red balls are very rare. Do you really want to start with a noninformative prior? If so, your approach seems OK, except maybe begin with what Bayesians insist is the _truly_ noninformative (Jeffreys) prior $\mathsf{Beta}(.5,.5).$ (But result will not by much different just by doing that.)

Comment: @BruceET - I’ve got two things going on. The 60 trials are not strong enough evidence to shift an a priori belief that $p<<1-p$ and an uninformed prior does not reflect my belief that $p<<1-p$. Since I can’t do anything about the evidence, I need to more carefully pick a prior. Beta$(2,160)$ gives a $48\%$ chance that $p\le 0.01$ which seems like a reasonable place to start. Updating this prior gives a posterior of Beta$(2,220)$ which gives me $E(p)=\frac{1}{111}$.

Comment: I made a typographical emendation, changing $p<<1-p$ to $p\ll 1-p.$ The latter is standard usage.

Comment: Definitely something like a Beta prior like the one you suggest is probably appropriate. Knowing which numbers to use may be impossible without more information than what you've given us. I suspect one could make an almost logical argument for the proposition that it should be $\operatorname{Beta}(1,\beta),$ i.e. that the first parameter should be $1,$ but right now I don't know how to do that. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I couldn’t recall the $\LaTeX$ code for it.